# Basic Linear Algebra Question: Rank and Surjectivity

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that given $f: U \to V$ is a linear transformation and $\dim(U)=\dim(V)$, then $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if the $\operatorname{rank}(f) = \dim(U)$.

I've got the injective part.  I just can't figure out how to prove that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Well, $\operatorname{rank}(f) = \dim f(U)$ is a subspace of $V$ of full dimension...

Comment: ok, gotcha. I can prove that image(f) is a subspace of V easily enough.  So that ought to do it, thanks.  ---  I realize it's "obvious" intuitively, and I don't really need to do it for this, but how would I go about proving that an n-dimensional subspace of an n-dimensional vector space is the SAME vector space?

Comment: If $X$ is a proper subspace of $Y$ then you can extend a basis of $X$ to a basis of $Y$. So $Y$ has to have a bigger dimension.

Comment: Right-o.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the rank-nullity theorem: (assuming that the spaces are finite dimensional)
$$\dim \text{Im } f+\dim\ker f=\dim U.$$
From here conclude that the kernel is zero, and hence the map is injective.

Note that your assertion is false in the infinite dimensional setting. For instance, consider the derivative operator on the set of real-coefficient polynomials
$$D\colon \mathbb{R}[X]\to \mathbb{R}[X].$$
Clearly, $D$ is onto (every polynomial has an antiderivative), but $D$ is not an isomorphism as it is not one-to-one.

Comment: Cool beans.  How do you know that every polynomial of infinite degree has an antiderivative?

Comment: Polynomials have finite degrees. $R[X]$ consists of polynomials of all degrees, that is, constants, linears, quadratics, etc. $D$ is defined as follows: $$D(a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n)=a_1+\dots+na_nx^{n-1}$$.

Comment: Right but the standard basis is {1, x, x^2, ... , x^n} in the finite dimensional case.  I would assume that in the infinite dimensional case the basis would be {1, x, x^2, ... x^INF} (I haven't studied infinite-dimensional vector spaces at all so that's just a guess).  Then what would be D(x^INF)?

Comment: A basis for $R[X]$ is given by $B=\{1, x, x^2, x^3, \dots\}$. Indeed, this is a linearly independent infinite set, and that's why $R[X]$ is an infinite dimensional vector space. Moreover, $B$ spans any polynomial in $R[X]$ (which is by definition of finite degree); this is because any polynomial is a linear combination of finitely many vectors in $B$.